# Creating links in DOORS using DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

I am using DOORS 8.3 and i want to create links DXL Can any one help me with the code. I have tried to find the presence of links in the module using DXL and it works properly. However I don't know the command to create links using DXL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a link in DXL you need 3 pieces of information:

`string linkMod = /Project/Folder/LinkModuleName` The full Link module path.

`Object src` the source object

`Object tgt` the Target object

You must have edit access to the Source object when you create the link. After you assign the variables above with the correct objects and the full link module path, you can use the operation below to create the link:

```
src -> linkMod -> tgt
```

That will create a link from the source to the target, using the link module specified.

Hope this helps.

---EDIT---

If your objects are in separate modules, you will need to open each of them to get the correct object handles.

```
Module smod = read("/PROJECT/FOLDER/SOURCE_MODULE") // Full path to source module
Object src = object(123)                            // Absolute number for source object in source module

Module tmod = read("/PROJECT/FOLDER/TARGET_MODULE") // Full path to target module
Object tgt = object(456)                            // Absolute number for target object in target module
```

Then the link is made the same way:

src -> linkMod -> tgt

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for your help. I am new to DXL and not being able to use this code properly please help me. I have two documents test and test1 stored in same folder. I have created a link module linker with source as test and target test1 test has a object background which I want to link with Center in test1.So, string linkMod="/Test/linker"  Object Background Object Cwenter than I used the command background->linkMod->center, this shows run time error unassigned variable background. Please help me with this.

Comment: You need to define the two object variables as I did above. You can set each one using its absolute number like `Object src = object(123)`, replacing the `123` with the absolute number from your background object. Then do the same with the center object as the `tgt`.

Comment: Added module specific information to the answer above. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @SteveValliere.. I did the same. But I end up with an error "Cannot create link: no access to source object". Any idea why this is happening? Could you please help me with this? `Module m = read("/xy/ xy Z/abc/abc2/abc3")`;`  `Module m2 = read("/xy/ xy Z/abc/abc2/def");` `Object o = object(2219); ` `Link newLink;` `Object o2= object(2461);` `string LinkMod="/xy/ xy Z/abc/abc2/TestLinking");` `newLink = o -> LinkMod -> o2;`