# how to link from one module to another using DXL in DOORs?

Tags: ibm-doors

I have to link two modules:
for ex: i have some information in module 'A' and the information in module 'B' which is similar to module 'A' and module 'C' has the same information. Now the linking is present between 'A' to 'B' and 'B' to 'C'. The target is to link 'C' to 'A'.

Comment: This question is too broad. Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Are you trying to link one single object in C to a single object in A? or are you trying to go through Module C and link all objects to the corresponding objects in A? Also, if you already have links from A to B and B to C, what is the point of linking C to A? You can show traceability without the extra set of links.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a link to a DOORS object which resides in a *different* module does not differ from creating a link to objects of the *same* module. You just have to retrieve the object handle from the module.

Consider this:

```
Object sourceObj = ... // you already have this object handle
Object targetObj = null
const string targetModuleName = "/my/DOORS/module"

// open the module
Module mod = edit(targetModuleName, true, false)
if (null(mod)) ack("Error!")

// now it depends on how you can identify your target object
for targetObj in mod do {
    // example: if the object identifier matches ...
    if (... == identifier(targetObj)) {
       sourceObj -> targetObj
       break
    }
}
```

Additionally, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642254/creating-links-in-doors-using-dxl) where Steve explains this scenario as well.